# Does setting an array element of type: object to null set the object value to null or just the array index?

Tags: javascript

I am working on a chess engine and I'm a little fuzzy on how value assignments work in complex use cases. (I realize this may not be complex to some of you but for me it is) I have a start function that initializes my pieces object and the board array.

```
start() {
        this.pieces = {};
        // first letter is rank, second letter is the piece, the second letter's capitalization is the color
        this.pieces.aP = new Pawn([6, 0], 'w');
        this.pieces.bP = new Pawn([6, 1], 'w');
        this.pieces.cP = new Pawn([6, 2], 'w');
        this.pieces.dP = new Pawn([6, 3], 'w');
        this.pieces.eP = new Pawn([6, 4], 'w');
        this.pieces.fP = new Pawn([6, 5], 'w');
        this.pieces.gP = new Pawn([6, 6], 'w');
        this.pieces.hP = new Pawn([6, 7], 'w');
        this.pieces.ap = new Pawn([1, 0], 'b');
        this.pieces.bp = new Pawn([1, 1], 'b');
        this.pieces.cp = new Pawn([1, 2], 'b');
        this.pieces.dp = new Pawn([1, 3], 'b');
        this.pieces.ep = new Pawn([1, 4], 'b');
        this.pieces.fp = new Pawn([1, 5], 'b');
        this.pieces.gp = new Pawn([1, 6], 'b');
        this.pieces.hp = new Pawn([1, 7], 'b');
        this.pieces.aR = new Rook([7, 0], 'w');
        this.pieces.bN = new Knight([7, 1], 'w');
        this.pieces.cB = new Bishop([7, 2], 'w');
        this.pieces.dQ = new Queen([7, 3], 'w');
        this.pieces.eK = new King([7, 4], 'w');
        this.pieces.fB = new Bishop([7, 5], 'w');
        this.pieces.gN = new Knight([7, 6], 'w');
        this.pieces.hR = new Rook([7, 7], 'w');
        this.pieces.ar = new Rook([0, 0], 'b');
        this.pieces.bn = new Knight([0, 1], 'b');
        this.pieces.cb = new Bishop([0, 2], 'b');
        this.pieces.dq = new Queen([0, 3], 'b');
        this.pieces.ek = new King([0, 4], 'b');
        this.pieces.fb = new Bishop([0, 5], 'b');
        this.pieces.gn = new Knight([0, 6], 'b');
        this.pieces.hr = new Rook([0, 7], 'b');

        this.board = [
            [this.pieces.ar,this.pieces.bn,this.pieces.cb,this.pieces.dq,this.pieces.ek,this.pieces.fb,this.pieces.gn,this.pieces.hr],
            [this.pieces.ap,this.pieces.bp,this.pieces.cp,this.pieces.dp,this.pieces.ep,this.pieces.fp,this.pieces.gp,this.pieces.hp],
            [null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null],
            [null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null],
            [null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null],
            [null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null],
            [this.pieces.aP,this.pieces.bP,this.pieces.cP,this.pieces.dP,this.pieces.eP,this.pieces.fP,this.pieces.gP,this.pieces.hP],
            [this.pieces.aR,this.pieces.bN,this.pieces.cB,this.pieces.dQ,this.pieces.eK,this.pieces.fB,this.pieces.gN,this.pieces.hR]
        ];
    }
```

Pieces are created with the following constructor

```
class Piece {
    constructor(position, color) {
        this.position = position
        this.color = color
    }
}
```

Moves have the following format. Element.position is referring to the same position from the piece constructor. [row, square] is split and used to call array elements in the this.board matrix. Piece is the name of the piece (ap would be the black a pawn). capture is whether or not the move is a capture, and multipliedVector is a vector used in other functions.

```
{
  source: element.position, 
  target: [row, square], 
  piece: piece, 
  move: multipliedVector, 
  capture: true
}
```

I then have a function called imagineMove. When called the move parameter is of the structure above. The purpose is that all it does is update the position, so that when I implement logic to the computer player, I can look forward with minimal computer resources used. All that it does is set the target square in the board matrix to the source and the source to null.

```
imagineMove(move) {
        this.savedPosition = this.board;
        
        this.board[move.target[0]][move.target[1]] = this.board[move.source[0]][move.source[1]];
        this.board[move.source[0]][move.source[1]] = null

        this.switchTurns()
    }
```

When I set the source to null, does anything change in the actual object (this.pieces) or does it simply change the board matrix? If the latter, is there a way I can access the object via the matrix? With making moves this doesn't really matter as everything is final, but with imagining them I don't want to mess up the data for a piece when I'm going to revert the board back to the this.savedPosition.

Comment: Could you update your question with examples of what you used? I'm talking about what is a move, what is the board etc.. It's hard to imagine what are you doing without examples

Answer (score 1):

Setting the board square to null only replaces the piece and only affects the board.
However this part is concerning

```
this.savedPosition = this.board;
```

You need to ensure that the board is duplicated so that you still have a saved position

```
this.savedPosition = [...this.board];
```

It's called a spread operator and it will make a copy of your board.

Also I highly recommend having the board only save piece names and not the actual pieces. You can always access them from this.pieces